# Pushing to Git with two accounts

Tags: git, github

I followed this [tuotrial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) on how to have two separate git accounts on the same machine.

I'm having trouble pushing changes from my second account, they always come from my first one or it says I do not have access rights.

Here's what I do:

Create a folder for my project on my computer and do

```
git init
```

Do a pull:

```
git pull https://github.com/panthro/test master
```

Then:

```
git remote add origin git@github-panthro:pantro/test.git
```

Then:

```
git push origin master
```

This gives the error:

```
ERROR: Permission to panthro/test.git denied to MyOriginalGitHubName.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Config:

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host github-panthro
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_panthro
```

Comment: You need to show your `.ssh/config` and the exact outputs of the commands you are getting. Without those we can't tell anything about what you did wrong.

Comment: Are you using `ssh-agent`? I recall reading about problem where ssh uses incorrect key if `ssh-agent` has some keys, but not the one you request with `IdentityFile` option.

Comment: One more thing to try is to write script (say `verbose-ssh.sh`) containing command `exec ssh -v -v -v "$@"` and setting environment variable `GIT_SSH=/path/to/verbose-ssh.sh`. Then it should tell you which keys it is trying to authenticate with so you can check whether it is trying to right ones.

Comment: I can push now but it's still pushing with my default username.

Comment: That was _not_ supposed to _fix_ anything. It was supposed to give us more information about what ssh is doing there. Did it print a lot of stuff? It should have. Add it to the question.

Comment: Nothing new was printed.

Answer (score 1):

You should first do this for your second account:

```
git remote -v
```

to see how many remotes do you have.

Then, you can remove the first remote with this code:

```
git remote rm <remote-name>
```

And finally use:

```
git remote add origin <url>
```