# Git Hub - 2 users / same machine

Tags: git, github

I've followed various posts and am getting very frustrated with this.

I want to have 2 git hub accounts on my machine, but when I push to my repository, my first account is always used.

Here is what I've done:

Created a new ssh key and added to git hub.
Created a config file:

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host github-panthro
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_panthro
```

Then:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github-panthro:panthro/myrepo.git
git push origin master
```

But it keeps pushing up changes by my original git hub user. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git with two accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443667/pushing-to-git-with-two-accounts)

Comment: Not a duplication, my error is different.

Comment: it's your identical question, in which you commented that it pushes with your original user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commits you pushnto github will appear authored by the user whose email matches the email you set with

```
git config --global user.email
```

But you can also config a local email on a per-repo basis if you omit the --global parameter. As you see, this email is linked to your working copy, so you can't have two emails here. What you can do, instead, is to have two working copies in your local machine, each one with its corresponding user email. Obviously you need to make sure they keep in sync somehow.

In second place, if you are using the same local user to push to github, and both working copies are using the ssh remote address, then you are using the same key to push, even if your commits do appear aliased by the two emails you previously set.

If you want to use different accounts for real, then you can either use the https remote address (which will make you authenticate before pushing) or you must set two users in your machine, each one with his own ssh key, and don't push with user A in the repo that has user's B email.

Edit: I just tried in one of my projects and it works (github didn't recognize my bogus email, so it displayed the user.name instead)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be a solution although, setting the local email on a per repo base fails to work, the global email supersedes it, any way around this?

Comment: Okay, I'll give it another shot. Thanks for your answer. Will accept asap.